# Replace All numeric substring with character

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have to replace all digit patterns with some character. For 1 digit its working fine  for e.g for given string `ramesh_gone_to_avbp_9_vc.pdf` its working fine changing it to `ramesh_gone_to_avbp_*_vc.pdf` but for given input `ramesh_gone_to_avbp_91_vc.pdf` its changing to `ramesh_gone_to_avbp_**_vc.pdf` but i want output like `ramesh_gone_to_avbp_*_vc.pdf`

This is what i tried so far

```
String ss = "ramesh_gone_to_avbp_92_vc.pdf";
System.out.println(ss.replaceAll("(?<=[\\d\\.])-(?=[\\d\\.])", "*"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply match on `\d+`, which matches groups of numbers of one or more digits:

```java
String ss = "ramesh_gone_to_avbp_92_vc.pdf";
String output = ss.replaceAll("\\d+", "*");
System.out.println(output);  // ramesh_gone_to_avbp_*_vc.pdf
```